# Managing Single Quotes while calling on a Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I stopped using LINQ and moved to stored procedures after much debate.  Now that I am using all stored procedures I am running into things that I took for granted with LINQ. One is the single quote.

A colleague showed me this method below to make it easier to call stored procedures without having to write it out the long way for every query. My problem now is dealing with data such as a persons name like `Mc'Kay` or `O'Reilly`. The single quotes mess up the string that I am passing it.

```
public static void exe(string sql)
{
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed) { con.Open(); }

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); con.Close();
    }
```

I have been using this method and another one very similar to it very frequently on the site.  What is the best way that i can clean up this method so that it will allow me to manipulate data that has ''' in it and still be secure/ safe from SQL injection. I hoping to do it in this method or with a helper method so i do not have to go to every query that has been written since i made this switch.

I call on stored procedures passing in the name of the procedure and then comma separating the params behind it. If the param is a string I surround it in single quotes.

Comment: If you use the only viable way - **parametrized queries** - then you never have these issues since the parameters will take care of all the gory details. So if you run into these issues, it's probably because you concatenate together your SQL statements including all the values to deal with - ***stop that right NOW!***

Comment: @marc_s so those methods are flawed. I do concatenate but the way it was explained to me it wasn't bad. But i guess he was wrong. I would call on a procedure like string sql = "sp_update 'jack','coke' ". Then pass that into my method above.

Comment: Seriously - ***don't do that!*** You should use a `SqlCommand` object, set to `CommandType.StoredProcedure` and set its `CommandText` to the name of the stored procedures, and then add the necessary `SqlParameter` instances, one for each parameter, and set their values.

Comment: Thank you! I will stop!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort answer: replace the single quote with two single quotes when composing your query. That's how you escape a single quote in SQL Server. I.e:

```
var escapedValue = originalValue.Replace("'","''");
```

Good advice: as told in all the comments, don't compose the query in this way, and use parameterized queries or stored procedures, and pass the parameter values: you'll avoid problems like numbers and dates parsing, SQL injection attacks, and a lot more of different, and many times, unexpected issues.

Besides, if you're using Stored Procedures, you must have the parameters already available. Do simply use them, please! That's really easy:

- set [the rigth command type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtype(v=vs.110).aspx)
- pass [the parameter values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx)
- execute the sp right as you do with your **dangerous queries**

In other words: simply create a command, set the commant type to stored procedure, set the stored procedure name, add the parameters with their values to the parameter collection, and exceute it. In this way you'll forget about the aforementioned concerns.

Comment: My biggest misconception on this was that i am calling on a stored procedure using this method.  But it is still wrong. I think the Right answer for this post is to not use this method.

Comment: I've expalined you how to do it in the right way, in the "good advice" section. Didn't you undertand it? Simply create a command, set the sp name, the commant type, add the parameters with their values to the parameter collection, and execute it. No more worries!! Updated my answer with this explanation